# How to filter the negative/positive values from a list in list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, loops

I just wanted the negative values in my sublist by filtering out all the positive values.

But I am facing the `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`  or sometimes

`TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable`. ( when there's array to integrate over ),

How to solve this issue ?

My attempt :-

```
A = [ [-0.234, -0.435, -0.333, 0.999, 0.432, 0.995], [-0.411, -0.205, -0.505, 0.605, 0.705, 0.505], [-0.468, -0.555, -0.343, 0.977, 0.477, 0.777], [-0.244, -0.478, -0.384, 0.931, 0.405, 0.782] ]



Negative_values = []

for i in A:
    for m in i:
        List_of_Negative_values = list(filter(lambda x: x <= 0, m))
        Negative_values.append(List_of_Negative_values)
        
print('Negative_values',Negative_values)
```

desired result

```
A = [ [-0.234, -0.435, -0.333], [-0.411, -0.205, -0.505], [-0.468, -0.555, -0.343], [-0.244, -0.478, -0.384] ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
[[i for i in value if i<0]for value in A]
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `m` is float, but `filter` requests an iterator.

Try this:

```py
Negative_values = [ list(filter(lambda x: x <= 0, sublist)) for sublist in A ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this *in situ* then:

```
A = [ [-0.234, -0.435, -0.333, 0.999, 0.432, 0.995], [-0.411, -0.205, -0.505, 0.605, 0.705, 0.505], [-0.468, -0.555, -0.343, 0.977, 0.477, 0.777], [-0.244, -0.478, -0.384, 0.931, 0.405, 0.782] ]

A[:] = [[v for v in e if v < 0] for e in A]

print(A)
```

Otherwise, if you want a new list then:

```
B = [[v for v in e if v < 0] for e in A]
```

**Output:**

```
[[-0.234, -0.435, -0.333], [-0.411, -0.205, -0.505], [-0.468, -0.555, -0.343], [-0.244, -0.478, -0.384]]
```

**Note:**

For this particular case this is significantly faster than filter

Answer (score 1):

Here basically we going inside list via two loops and check if number is smaller then zero, if yes then take number or return None. Finally we are filter the None values using filter function.

Code:

```
[(lambda x: list(filter(None,[num if num<0 else None for num in x])))(x) for x in A]
```

Output:

```
[[-0.234, -0.435, -0.333],
[-0.411, -0.205, -0.505],
[-0.468, -0.555, -0.343],
[-0.244, -0.478, -0.384]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        A = [ [-0.234, -0.435, -0.333, 0.999, 0.432, 0.995], [-0.411, -0.205, -0.505, 0.605, 0.705, 0.505], [-0.468, -0.555, -0.343, 0.977, 0.477, 0.777], [-0.244, -0.478, -0.384, 0.931, 0.405, 0.782] ]
        
        #there no need of double loop filter run through lists
   
           Negative_values = []
        
        for i in A:
            my_list = list(filter(lambda x: x<0, i))
            Negative_values.append(my_list)
 print('Negative_values',Negative_values)
         
        
Out[]: 
Negative_values [[-0.234, -0.435, -0.333], [-0.411, -0.205, -0.505], [-0.468, -0.555, -0.343], [-0.244, -0.478, -0.384]]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).